# Using Axios to grab GitHub Stars

Tags: github, get, axios, github-api

I am using axios for a JavaScript (on Mac) assignment, and I am trying to grab the number of starred items through GitHub's API. When I looked through res.data, I only saw res.data.starred_url, which only gives the starred URL. I am looking, specifically, for the **number of starred items a user has**. It looks like it may require a separate API call, but I'm not sure how to structure it in axios.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this, or has anyone done this before with success?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It needs to be an axios call for the user's starred URL, but you need to use a template literal to grab the GitHub API call's username value. It does need to be a separate API call, but it's very simple. One must put this specific axios call before the main GitHub axios call and close it AFTER both axios calls. `res.data[0].stargazers_count` is what will give you the number of stars:

```
  axios
  .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${answers.name}/starred`)
  .then(function(res) {
    let stars = res.data[0].stargazers_count;
```